# How do I manage registrations on a different domain than my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a Rails app at www.myapp.com, and I have a marketing landing page at www.marketingpage.com.

What I want to happen is, when people fill out a registration form on my marketing page, for it to be managed by my Rails app.

I am thinking of just creating a view at myapp.com/mktg, then just having www.marketingpage.com redirect to myapp.com/mktg.

But, the issue with that approach is that I don't want users to see a different domain name for the registration.

How can I approach this, so that the registration on the marketing page looks and feels like it is a full 'mini-site', but it is powered by my main Rails App?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

Another thing is, for the registration page at marketingpage.com, I want to use email sign-up [only for Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How%20To%3a%20Email-only%20sign-up) - so the marketingpage.com is not just 1 page. It will be 1 page, then they at least 1 or 2 more pages. So whatever domain/routing strategy, has to account for that too.

Comment: You could add a special sign-up API to your rails app to be used exclusively by your page at www.marketingpage.com.

Comment: @cdesrosiers - I don't have an API for my Rails App. I suppose I could create one, but that seems like overkill for what I want to do...no?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a full-blown API. For example, you could use javascript to send some JSON containing the email address and other info to a controller action in your rails app that will create a user record and return confirmation.

Comment: Oh I see....so the target URL would be `myapp.com/controller#action`, and then just be updated, and the marketing page would just be HTML/CSS/jQuery?

Comment: An issue with that is part of the functionality of the marketing page, will be say a 'list' of users that have registered. I would then have to create an action to list users that have registered, right?

Comment: Yeah, you can just query your rails app for the list of users.

Comment: Hrmm...interesting. That's one approach. Thanks. If you want to put that as answer, with maybe some sample code or something, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an email input:

```
<input id="email"></input>
<button id="submit-email"></button>
```

you can send a jsonp (to get around same-origin restrictions) request when the button is clicked:

```
$('#submit-email').click(function() {
    submitted_email = $('#email').value()

    // client-side validations

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://www.myapp.com/signup",
        data: { user: { email: submitted_email } },
        success: function(data) {
            // signup success
        }
    });
});
```

On the rails end:

```
class UserController
    def signup
        @user = User.create(params[:user])
        // handle success/failure
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render :json => @user }
        end  
    end
end
```

To retrieve a list of users:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://www.myapp.com/users",
        success: function(data) {
            // populate a list
        }
    });
```

Comment: How do I implement some amount of security, so random scripts can't get access to my data? The more I think about it, the more that security aspect is making me nervous. Thoughts about that?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but it would boil down to sending an authenticity_token along with the data and checking on rails end.

Comment: Yeh....this solution is getting more complicated to make it done right. I think I may go with just doing a regular view and try to do some domain trickery.